# Do I need to reinstall NetBeans to its latest version in order to get its latest features?

Tags: netbeans

This question has been bothered me for a long time, and I guess it's too general and basic so that a quick google can never point me to the right answer.

For example, 7.3.1 has just been released, and my currently installed NetBeans (7.3) notified me that there were some components to be upgraded. After I did the upgrade and restarted NetBeans, its title bar still shows 7.3.

So, are the new features of 7.3.1 included in my NetBeans now?

If so, can anybody give me the link of the official documentation that mentions this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7.3 is the same as version 7.3.1. You are talking about the same thing. Now upgrades to components is different.

Now by upgrading components you receive new functionality and fixes **on the actual plugins** and NOT on the IDE engine itself.

Bottom line, yes your IDE is up to date now despite the fact that the plugins might not be completely up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, at the beginning, your answer was still confusing to me, because:

Comment: 1. You said "Version 7.3 is the same as version 7.3.1", but I found the following on the [NetBeans7.3 Patches Info page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans7.3PatchesInfo)
> NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (or Patch 2 for NetBeans 7.3) is an update to NetBeans IDE 7.3 and contains fixes for following bugs.
I assume you might mean **after installing the latest update (Patch 2), ** 7.3 and 7.3.1 are the same.
2. I see no way to confirm that the latest update has been installed to the IDE, nor the title bar or Help -> About, which is not following the common sense and is quite annoying to a geek...

Comment: 3. In the "Upgrading and Multiple Installation Support section" of the [NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html), it says
> Note: Incremental version upgrades of the IDE cannot be performed at this time. To upgrade to the most recent version you must download the latest installer.